# Big mess with databases on my local OSX server

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, pid

I run mavericks and today i wanted to try and setup Sierra on another partition
I setup apache,mysql,phpmyadmin etc and i thought would be nice idea to use the mysql/data folder of my main mavericks so i can try the server on the Sierra partition by using my databases from Mavericks..
There were some issues related to pid so i thought ok that's enough and i restarted to Mavericks as normal.
From this point start my nightmare.. i had the common error  `ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!` etc.
I decided to update mysql version and the problems still continue, i manage to fix only by delete the `_ibdata1` only then mysql started with "success"
But i cannot use the databases now, they are corrupted although i can see them as normal in phpmyadmin (not normal now that i check , the tables are empty)

I have all the old data folder in a backup as before, is there any magic way to bring everything back to normal?
Apart of the pid thing i did not delete anything else , so everything should be there.
The `_ibdata1` is about 10GB cause i have a lot of databases (most of them i do not need to be honest.

Please advise

Comment: MySQL doesn't work that way, you can't necessarily grab the data folder from one installation and put it over the top of a different installation of a different (or even the same) version. Your best bet is probably to restore your Mavericks machine to the point the databases are accessible, then use mysqldump to export a dump which you then import into the new server

Comment: no restore point :(

Comment: What are "Sierra" and "Mavericks"?

Comment: Operating Systems , i did manage to resolve all my issues and i did also updated to mySQL 5.7.16 something that i was afraiding to do because of errors!I am so happy , i will update my post with some tricks that might help others users after i double check anything :)